# Why does one have to enter subnet mask instead of simply number of 1-bits in the mask?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, subnet

As I understand, subnet mask [must be contiguous](https://superuser.com/a/601267/87525). So e.g. you can't have a mask of 255.1.0.0. The networks are often denoted as e.g. 192.168.5.0/24, which automatically contains all the information to derive the subnet mask, and with such a derivation it is guaranteed to be contiguous.

Why do the users have to manually "expand" this number 24 into 255.255.255.0 instead of simply entering the number 24 into network configuration? Is there any case where subnet mask would be required and the number of 1-bits in the mask not sufficient for configuration?

Comment: It depends of software (including firmware). You must use those form of mask format which the software understands. *subnet mask must be contiguous* - no, there are sparse masks, but the most part of software cannot work with them correctly.

Comment: This doesn't answer why it is this way (that's due to software only) but this does answer what a 'valid' vs an invalid mask looks like -> https://superuser.com/questions/601252/is-225-225-225-128-a-valid-subnet-mask

Comment: @djsmiley2k this is the very link I've initially put in the OP as confirmation of my understanding.

Comment: I assume you're asking specifically about e.g. Windows users? Many systems do accept the /plen syntax or just the number, as does e.g. the "new" Settings app in Win10.

Comment: I am voting to close this as primarily opinion based as the reason why it is entered a certain way is probably based purely on the preference of the developer at one time, and giving a reason would be largely speculative. I am guessing that 192.168.1.1/255.255.255.0 or 192.168.1.1/24 was just simpler than 192.168.1.1/11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000 for users

Comment: @grawity I'm asking not only about Windows. Everywhere I tried to configure network was like this: Windows XP adapter properties dialog (didn't use Windows much since), KDE's NetworkManager GUI, Linux console `ifconfig` utility, Debian's `/etc/network/interfaces` file, web interfaces of various routers, etc..

Comment: Debian's `/etc/network/interfaces` has accepted prefix lengths for a few years now, as has `ifconfig` (though the latter hasn't been _maintained_ for years), as has GNOME's NetworkManager interface (although not yet KDE's).

Comment: @grawity good to know. Now I see things are changing, although it's still strange that this mask format has been prevalent for so much time without real reason (unless there is one).

Answer (score 0):

It is simply software dependant.

When the RFC's are written up, they generally won't define how a value is presented to a end user, only how it 'works'. So you end up with the effect you've seen where different programs implement the same number in different ways.

The same subnet presented in different ways:

- 255.255.255.0
- /24
- 11111111.11111111.11111111.00000000

The same can be seen with the presentation of mac addresses:

- Cisco formats in IOS: FFFF.FFFF.FFFF
- Microsoft cli does: FF-FF-FF-FF-FF-FF
- Microsoft DHCP: FFFFFFFFFFFF
- Most network card manufcturers: FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF

These all represent the same mac address, just in different forms.