# Why is 172.16/12 contiguous?

Tags: networking, netmask

I'm confused.

From [RFC 1918](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1918):

```
10.0.0.0        -   10.255.255.255  (10/8 prefix)
172.16.0.0      -   172.31.255.255  (172.16/12 prefix)
192.168.0.0     -   192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

The prefix `172.16/12` seems strange to me for the range `16`-`31`. Masks are [supposed to use contiguous binary 1s](https://superuser.com/a/601267/942694).

A prefix of `/12` for contiguous 1s should indicate:

```
11111111.11110000
```

Only `172.16` (`10101100.00010000`) is masked by that range. All non-`16` bits for oclets `17`-`31` are not protected by the mask.

But, the binary mask to cover `172.16` - `172.31` is

```
11111111.00011111
```

*List of `172.16` - `172.31`:*

```
10101100.00010000
10101100.00011111
10101100.00011110
10101100.00011101
10101100.00011100
10101100.00011011
10101100.00011010
10101100.00011001
10101100.00011000
10101100.00010111
10101100.00010110
10101100.00010101
10101100.00010100
10101100.00010011
10101100.00010010
10101100.00010001
```

So, a prefix of `172.16/16` (`11111111.11111111`) to mask all these makes more sense to me.

Is this RFC 1918 range of `172.16.0.0` - `172.31.255.255` not contiguous?

Or does a `/12` prefix actually indicate:

```
11111111.00001111
```

But, that number range only goes to `15`, in which case we need:

```
11111111.00011111
```

And, that should be `172.16/13`, if it is not contiguous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Only `172.16` (`10101100.00010000`) is masked by that range. All oclets 17-31 are not protected by the mask.

No, that's not true. All octets from 16 to 31 are covered by the mask equally, because they all have the form `0001xxxx`.

The purpose of netmasks is to indicate the **static** part of the address, and if you look at the list in your post, the first 12 contiguous bits are static while the rest are variable. That's why the first octet of the mask is `11111111`, after all, and not `00000000` – it indicates that all eight bits (of the `172`) are fixed, and likewise the second octet is `11110000` to indicate that the first 4 bits are fixed.

But even if the netmask was indicating the variable part, it would still be contiguous because the last 4 bits of the 2nd octet *and* all bits of the 3rd-4th octets are variable, with no gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Per [this patient answer by u1686_grawity](https://superuser.com/a/1836276/942694), the mask does not cover *possible* numbers, but *unchangable* numbers!

```
11111111.11110000
```

Protects the first twelve spaces:

```
10101100.0001xxx
```

allowing that range of `16`-`31`

Comment: Even if it covered the possible numbers, it would also cover the `.0.0`–`.255.255`, and it would still be contiguous as a result. The problem wasn't exactly about which way it goes, but about it being consistent from octet to octet – in your post, you tried to apply it in opposite ways between octet 1 and octet 2.

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes. I consider it a rookie mistake. I'm sure many beginners will find it a valuable answer. It's through that fourth `1` in the second oclet that the `/12` locks down, everything else could be anything else, hence the range of `16-31`. It all makes sense now.